# how change database's port dynamically(django)

Tags: django, django-database

i have a django project that it should have ability to change the database's port dynamically for security reasons.

for example there should be a template like ( port= ) and the administrator should enter a port and change the default one. how to do this?

thanks.

Comment: I'm curious why would you like to do it? This sounds like a desparate measure and will not quarantee security at all. Are you sure you are solving correct problem?

Comment: this is one part of a project that they asked me to do , is there any way to do this? @BartoszStasiak

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLite database which comes embedded in Django by default so in order to change the database port you have to change the run server port of Django also.

You can add these mentioned below  lines  in your manage.py file

from django.core.management.commands.run server import Command as run server
runserver.default_port="8001"